# Ebean optimistic locking - version column vs all columns?

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean, optimistic-locking

I see that Ebean supports both ways but what are the real world differences between using @version or all approach? Any reason not to use @version everywhere with Ebean?

http://www.avaje.org/occ.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any reason to stay with the "all columns" version if you have control over the models yourself. The advantages of the "all" method as I see them are:

1. It's easier for the developer – there's no coding at all involved so this method works even for developers who have no idea of what concurrency checking is.
2. It's foolproof. By checking each and every column against the expected values you can be sure that you're never going to overwrite someone's change

On the other hand, it's less efficient (checking all columns is more work than just checking a single column). I have also had problems with cascaded deletes in Play Framework, where ebean thought that the data in the database had changed.

The drawbacks of the version scheme that I can come up with are

- If you forget to update your version field sometimes when you update the object, then you won't get any lock protection for those updates. This bug will be really hard to find because everything will work perfectly most of the time.
- If you don't already have a version or "last changed" field in the database, you will have to add a new column which naturally takes a bit of space and time.

I don't think either of these drawbacks are serious. If you know what you are doing (and you've proved that already by asking the question ;) ) and you feel confident that you won't forget to update your version field, then go ahead!